# libgl1-mesa-glx is not configured yet

Tags: 11.04, apt, package-management

Since my `sudo apt-get upgrade` today I have this weird error(s) in the end of each software installation with apt-get, for instance :

```
    $apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liblzo2-2 uswsusp
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libglu1-mesa
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libglu1-mesa
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/165 kB of archives.
After this operation, 561 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Selecting previously deselected package libglu1-mesa.
(Reading database ... 140491 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libglu1-mesa (from .../libglu1-mesa_7.10.2-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx (7.10.2-0ubuntu2.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules is already managed by x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf.
dpkg: error processing libgl1-mesa-glx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglu1-mesa:
 libglu1-mesa depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libglu1-mesa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx
 libglu1-mesa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone know how to repair that ? I have tried `apt-get purge` or `apt-get install` on 'these' packages back did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have finally fixed it with uninstalling `nvidia-common`

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-common`

and reintalling the drivers with `Additional drivers` GUI

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by this line:

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules is already managed by x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf.
```

*In this case*, it's harmless to force configuration of `libgl1-mesa-glx` and solve your problems.

Run:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all --configure libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Followed by:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And then (just in case):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

---

To force-install that specific `libgl1-mesa-glx` from scratch, please do:

```
wget http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu//pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-glx_7.10.2-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --force-all -i libgl1-mesa-glx_7.10.2-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer: After that I receive : [http://pastebin.com/Kpk3KHtC](http://pastebin.com/Kpk3KHtC)

Comment: @lordmonkey: please try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force libgl1-mesa-glx` instead. Are you logged in as root? I noticed you're not using `sudo`...

Comment: :/ [http://pastebin.com/a7g3pZYD](http://pastebin.com/a7g3pZYD)

Comment: @lordmonkey: please see edit at bottom of answer to try force-installing from scratch.

Comment: which line do you mean exactly ? I have tried `sudo apt-get -f instal` but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @lordmonkey: sorry, I'd forgotten to save the edit :) Please see now (`wget ...`)

Comment: Ok I have tried your method but I get something telling me that I `libgl1-mesa-glx` is already configured by something else (I don't remember). But I have finally fixed it with removing `nvidia-common` and reinstalling nvidia drivers from `Additional drivers` GUI